# Set cell value in corresponding row in named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have named range $A:$A **Stored_Numbers** and range $B:$B **Corrected_Numbers**.

**Stored_Numbers** is a list of phone numbers and **Corrected_Numbers** is empty (to start with).

I want to go through the list of phone numbers, run some code on the current phone number, and set the result in the corresponding cell in **Corrected_Numbers**.

How do I set the value of the corresponding cell in **Corrected_Numbers**?

```
Sub Correct_Phone_Number()

    ' Declare variable storedNumber
    Dim storedNumber As String

    ' Declare variable correctedNumber
    Dim correctedNumber As String

    ' Select cell A1, *first line of data*.
    Range("Stored_Numbers")(1, 1).Select

    ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        ' Set variable storedNumber
        storedNumber = ActiveCell

        'Run some code.....

        ' Set variable correctedNumber
        correctedNumber = result

        ' Step down 1 row from present location.
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = correctedNumber` did the trick!

```
Sub Correct_Phone_Number()

    ' Declare variable storedNumber
    Dim storedNumber As String

    ' Declare variable correctedNumber
    Dim correctedNumber As String

    ' Select cell A1, *first line of data*.
    Range("Stored_Numbers")(1, 1).Select

    ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        ' Set variable storedNumber
        storedNumber = ActiveCell

        ' Set variable correctedNumber
        correctedNumber = storedNumber


        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = correctedNumber

        ' Step down 1 row from present location.
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

End Sub
```